# Send cmdlet output and another variable to a CSV file

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a list of Office 365 users that I want to reset the passwords for. I would like to reset the password for each user and then output the username and password to a CSV file.

Using the `Set-MsolUserPassword` cmdlet only returns the password, so I'm a bit stuck.

So far, this is what I have:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
foreach ( $name in $names ) {
    $newPassword = $([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(9,1))
    Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $name.UserPrincipalName -ForceChangePassword 1 -NewPassword $newPassword -TenantId $tenID
    }
```

This returns a long list of passwords. What I would like it to do is return a CSV file containing $name.UserPrincipalName and $newPassword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to add the new password as an additional property to your existing objects, and then select out the 2 properties you want for export:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
foreach ( $name in $names ) {
    $newPassword = $([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(9,1))
    Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $name.UserPrincipalName -ForceChangePassword 1 -NewPassword $newPassword -TenantId $tenID
    $name | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NewPassword -Value $newPassword -PassThru
    }

$names | 
 select UserPrincipalName,NewPassword |
 Export-Csv c:\somedir\somefile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should get you going in a productive direction:

```
$passwordList = @()
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
foreach ( $name in $names ) {

    $newPassword = $([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(9,1))
    Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $name.UserPrincipalName -ForceChangePassword 1 -NewPassword $newPassword -TenantId $tenID
    $temp = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{'Name' = $name; 'Password' = $newPassword;}
    $passwordList += $temp
    }
$passwordList | Export-CSV C:\PATH\TO\File.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this by creating a brand new table from scratch:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
$PasswordTable = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "PasswordTable"
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn UserPrincipalName,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn NewPassword,([string])
$PasswordTable.Columns.Add($col1)
$PasswordTable.Columns.Add($col2)
foreach ( $name in $names ) {
    $newPassword = $([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,1))
    Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $name.UserPrincipalName -ForceChangePassword 1 -NewPassword $newPassword [-TenantId $tenID]
    $row = $PasswordTable.NewRow()
    $row.UserPrincipalName = $name.UserPrincipalName
    $row.NewPassword = $newPassword
    $PasswordTable.Rows.Add($row)
    }
$PasswordTable | Export-Csv C:\path\to\file.csv
```

But honestly I prefer mjolinor's answer :)